# Is there a universal MapPath function for both client-side and server-side apps?

Tags: .net, server.mappath

What is the universal MapPath equivalent to the below? Universal, meaning, that I could use it in both client-side and server-side .NET apps, not just in server-side apps.

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(virtualPath)
```

The reason I'm asking is I want to reuse the same piece of code in MVC.NET server-side apps, but as well in .NET standalone apps running on the client machine. Therefore I want to have a universal function to map my virtual paths to within my App's root folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no universal method for that, because there is no exact equivalent of the web root in a desktop application.

You could roll your own method that does different things depending on whether a web context exists or not, but then you would have to reference the `System.Web` dll in all your desktop applications also, which would certainly contradict any gain you are trying to make by reusing some of your code.